# Calculus 2 problems help

Tags: calculus, area, volume

[image]

Ive been struggling with this  problem. Thanks!

Comment: This seems like a fairly rudimentary problem, and this site discourages you just posting a problem like this without showing your own attempts and your own understanding, because it comes off as if you just want us to do your homework for you. What do you understand of the problem, and what have you tried? Where specifically are you stuck?

Comment: I should have clarified better, i understand all of part a, for art b i tried  using the washer method with the parabola as the top function and the line as the bottom, is this correct?

Comment: then for part c I wrote each function as a function of y and then split it into two different problems, a disk method with the line and x=4, and washer method with the two different sides of the parabola and x=4, is this correct?

Comment: @Rdog60 It's better to post your efforts in the body of the question, where it has a better chance if being seen. Also, it makes your question look more likely to be answered.

Answer (score 1):

A)  integral just measures the area under the function. So find the area under your top curve (parabola) and subtract it by the bottom curve (the line). The bounds are the intersections of your functions.

B) The are of the rotation can be calculated  with discs/ washers. To do this, use the formula of the circle with your radius equaling the top curve and then subtract it from the bottom volume bounded by the rotation of the bottom curve.

C) now split your region into two and use $y$ as your variable instead of $x$.

I will be more than happy to expand on my answer if you show your work and tell us where you are stuck/unsure.